# How do you create a scrollable TW3ListMenu at run-time?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

How do you create a scrollable TW3ListMenu at run-time?

I need something a little better for scrolling vertically through 50 items
I'd like to use a TW3ListMenu and just display the caption and a icon to the right ">" to click - then display the additional information on a secondary form.

How do I create a scrollable list of items using a TW3ListMenu?

I created the TW3ListMenu on a TW3ScrollBox, but it does not seem to scroll

Maybe its the layout ?

```
procedure TfrmMain.InitializeObject;
var
 i: Integer;
procedure AddMenuItem(caption: string);
var
 li: TW3ListItem;
begin
 li := fListMenu.Items.Add;
 li.Text := caption;
 li.OnClick :=
 procedure (Sender: TObject)
 begin
  //ShowMessage('You clicked: ' + (Sender as TW3ListItem).Text);
 end;
end; //addmenu


begin
  inherited;
  {$I 'frmMain:impl'}


   fHeader:= TW3HeaderControl.Create(self);
   fHeader.Height:= 50;
   fHeader.Title.Caption := 'Mountains';
   fHeader.Title.AlignText:= taCenter;
   fHeader.BackButton.Visible:= False;
   fHeader.StyleClass:= 'TW3Header';


   fBackButton:= TMenuButton.Create(self);
   fBackButton.Caption:= 'Back';
   fBackButton.Height:=  50;
   fBackButton.StyleClass:= 'TMenuButton';
   fBackButton.OnClick:= BackButtonClick;


   fScrollBox:= TW3Scrollbox.Create(self);
   fListMenu:= TW3ListMenu.Create(fScrollbox);

   For i:= 1 to 46 do
   AddMenuItem(IntToStr(i));




   FLayout :=
    Layout{1}.Client(Layout{2}.Margins(5).Spacing(5), [
     Layout{3}.Top(fHeader),
     Layout{4}.Client(fScrollbox),
     Layout{5}.Bottom(fBackButton)]);
end;
```

I even tried two layouts....

```
fScrollBox:= TW3Scrollbox.Create(self);
   fListMenu:= TW3ListMenu.Create(fScrollbox);
   For i:= 1 to 46 do
   AddMenuItem(IntToStr(i));

   FScrollLayout :=
    Layout{1}.Client(Layout{2}.Margins(5).Spacing(5), [
    Layout{3}.Client(fScrollbox)]);


   FLayout :=
    Layout{1}.Client(Layout{2}.Margins(5).Spacing(5), [
     Layout{3}.Top(fHeader),
     Layout{4}.Client(fScrollLayout),
     Layout{5}.Bottom(fBackButton)]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

warleyalex posted a solution on the [Smart Mobile Studio form](http://forums.smartmobilestudio.com/index.php?/topic/3798-scroll-able-control-for-storing-data-columns/)

A solution which uses the [qtxlibrary](http://qtxlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)